# flutter : i can't keep user login

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i want to keep user login after his first login but in every time i'm closing the application from the phone's background the user logged out and must login from start again

this is my api method to login

```
Future<dynamic> login(String email, String password ) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': email, 'password': password  };

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    http.Response response = await http.post(Environment.userLogin,
        body: json.encode(body), headers: Environment.requestHeader);

        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['code'] == 200) {

      _user = User.fromJson(res['message']);

      prefs.setString('email', _user.email);
      results = true;
    } else {

      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['error'], status: false);
    }

    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
```

and this is the main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = prefs.getString('email');
  print(email);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]).then((_) => runApp(new MyApp()));

}
```

can any one help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d49c3b8a27a3bb74cc2d9732e2d8ff42)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

          final isLoggedIn = snapshot.data.getString("email") != null;
          return isLoggedIn ? Home() : Login();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?